# Creating bitmap index- ora-00921

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, bitmap

I'm trying to create a bitmap index. My code is the following:

```
CREATE BITMAP INDEX citizen_idx
ON profiles (contracts.citizenID)
FROM profiles JOIN contracts
USING (citizenID) ;
```

And I get the following error:

> ORA-00921: unexpected end of SQL command

Does anybody know what's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your tables so I *improvized*. Basically, your syntax was wrong. Don't use explicit `JOIN`.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE profiles (citizenid NUMBER);

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE contracts
  2  (
  3     citizenid   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  4     contractid  NUMBER
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE BITMAP INDEX idx
  2     ON profiles (p.citizenid)
  3     FROM profiles p, contracts c
  4     WHERE c.citizenid = p.citizenid;

Index created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! My professor told us to use JOIN... Now I can see it was incorrect

Comment: You're welcome. If professor meant "join" (as a term), then they were right because - although *oldfashioned*, this is still a *join*. If they thought about explicitly using JOIN keyword, yes - that was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ANSI JOIN syntax in BITMAP Join INDEXES. It is mentioned in this [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4277286)

The same index you can create using old syntax like below

```
      CREATE BITMAP INDEX citizen_idx
      ON profiles (contracts.citizenID)
      FROM profiles,contracts
      where profiles.citizenID=contracts.citizenID;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!